# How can I do a vlookup loop with a repeating range?

Tags: excel

I am doing a Vlookup over a large section of data but the data is very repetitive and I would like to do a loop to prevent an extremely long formula. 
The format of the data is two columns with a name in the first column and a number in the second that repeats several hundred times. For example, 3 repetitions of the data (6 columns) would look like:

```
Abby 4   Sam  4  Mike 0
Bob  2   Rob  3  Tom  2
Mike 3   Adam 1  Sam  3
```

The Vlookup uses the name as the lookup_value and needs to sum all the numbers next to the name for each time they occur. Is there a way to do this as a vlookup type loop or an easier way to do it? 
Thank you!

Comment: so Sam is intended to have 7 as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$E$4=C10), ($B$2:$F$4))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, Sam would have 7 ! Thank you for your quick response and I think this is definitely the function to use. The only issue I was having was that some of the names were not working. So Sam and Mike were working but not Abby (would just display 0). Do you know why this would be?

Comment: I didn't 'lock' the ranges with absolute addressing. You probably filled down or copied the formula to a new location and the ranges shifted.